# Did I break R markdown? Every file I try gives the error "! Undefined control sequence. l.128 \cs_new:Npe \__color_backend_devicen_colorants:n #1

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I have an R markdown file that a former coworker wrote, and it worked fine until I made some edits. Suddenly I couldn't compile the pdf, and even scripts that were previously working gave the same error (below.) They would create a tex file then suddenly stop. Finally I opened a new R markdown file, and tried to run the sample one that appeared. I still got the same error message. The code and error are below:

````
---
title: "testing"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-10-13"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

And here is the output:

```
processing file: testing-r-markdown.Rmd
                                                                                                     
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testing-r-markdown.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output testing-r-markdown.tex --lua-filter "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-43~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\PAGEBR~1.LUA" --lua-filter "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-43~1.1\library\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\LATEX-~1.LUA" --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
output file: testing-r-markdown.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.128 \cs_new:Npe
                  \__color_backend_devicen_colorants:n #1 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile testing-r-markdown.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See testing-r-markdown.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I know very little about R markdown, so I don't really understand what this could be. I deleted my R history and the temporary files associated with each markdown file, and even moved the testing file into a different folder but everything gives the same error. I googled it and there were literally zero results. Can anyone help me figure out what this means?  Tried deleting temporary tex and txt files, and moved the file location. cleared R environment. Still gave the same error message.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Can you show your intermediate .tex file so we can narrow down where your problem comes from?

Comment: You didn't break R Markdown. It's likely to be a TeX Live (TinyTeX) problem, which has been reported at https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/issues/424#issuecomment-1761658222. The simple solution is to reinstall TinyTeX: `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`.

Comment: In the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77291118/tinytex-or-knitr-error-undefined-control-sequence-l-128-cs-newnpe-color where somebody else had the same problem, the log clearly showed that there was a mismatch between the L3 programming layer in the format and the backend files being loaded. Maybe for some reason the format wasn't recreated .

Comment: Thank you.I tried was tinytex:::refresh_all(), which didn't fix it. I tried tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(), and got the following error message:
Error in uninstall_tinytex() : 
  Detected TeX Live at "C:\texlive\2023", but it appears to be TeX Live instead of TinyTeX. To uninstall TeX Live, use the argument force = TRUE.
> uninstall_tinytex(force = TRUE)
Error in uninstall_tinytex(force = TRUE) : 
  could not find function "uninstall_tinytex"
texlive is a folder in my C drive, but the R package viewer doesn't list texlive, or any tex package besides tinytex. Do I need to uninstall texlive?

Comment: Turns out I did have TexLive installed, which was preventing me from refreshing TinyTex. I was able to uninstall TexLive and it works again. Thank you!