# tinytex or knitr error: "Undefined control sequence. l.128 \cs_new:Npe \__color_backend_devicen_colorants"

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, tinytex

Two days ago, I started getting a weird error whenever I tried to knit a PDF document in Rmarkdown. I get this error now whenever I try to knit to PDF on this computer, using tinytex and knitr. The error is completely mysterious in that I can't find any other reference to it elsewhere on the web, I can't find any mention of the control sequence it complains about in the intermediate .knit.md or .tex files, and the content.

I'm posting this question because I have tried updating to the latest version of tinytex, so I'm now on version 4.7, and updating to the latest version of knitr, so I'm now on 1.44, and I'm on R 4.3.1 and I've restarted RStudio and R and I've restarted my entire computer, and none of that has helped.

So any suggestions for how I should proceed would be greatly appreciated.

The full knit message:

```
processing file: temp_rmarkdown_doc.Rmd
                                                                                                  
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS temp_rmarkdown_doc.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output temp_rmarkdown_doc.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
output file: temp_rmarkdown_doc.knit.md

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log temp_rmarkdown_doc.log.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.128 \cs_new:Npe
                  \__color_backend_devicen_colorants:n #1 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile temp_rmarkdown_doc.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See temp_rmarkdown_doc.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

This is the file I tried to knit:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-10-11"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.
````

(I previously tried with other files but this is a much simpler example that's causing the same error.)

The intermediate .tex file:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Untitled},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{Untitled}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}2023-10-11}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\hypertarget{r-markdown}{%
\subsection{R Markdown}\label{r-markdown}}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax
for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.

\end{document}
```

The full .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.9.22)  14 OCT 2023 12:33
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**temp_rmarkdown_doc.tex
(./temp_rmarkdown_doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
)) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count194
\leftroot@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count196
\DOTSCASE@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count199
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count266
\dspbrk@lvl=\count267
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count268
\column@=\count269
\maxfields@=\count270
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks22
\inpenc@posthook=\toks23
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks24
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count271
\Gm@cntv=\count272
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count273
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen151
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen152
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen153
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen154
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen155
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen157
\Gm@dimlist=\toks25
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen158
\Gin@req@width=\dimen159
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hypertext links for LaTeX
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-08-07 v2.53 Cross-referencing by name of section
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count274
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count275
)
\@linkdim=\dimen160
\Hy@linkcounter=\count276
\Hy@pagecounter=\count277
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count278
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4050.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4167.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4172.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4175.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4434.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count279
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4772.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen161
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count280
\Field@Width=\dimen162
\Fld@charsize=\dimen163
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6051.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6056.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6059.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6066.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6081.
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count281
\c@Item=\count282
\c@Hfootnote=\count283
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count284
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count285
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 285.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip53
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 72.
(c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
) (c:/Users/Louise.LOUISE-DESKTOP/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-10-10 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count286
! Undefined control sequence.
l.128 \cs_new:Npe
                  \__color_backend_devicen_colorants:n #1 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10196 strings out of 476893
 155195 string characters out of 5806206
 1917785 words of memory out of 5000000
 31398 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 561822 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,0n,79p,323b,382s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Just guessing, but it looks as though your tex setup is broken.  Maybe you are mixing up old and new versions?  You could try `tinytex::uninstall_tinytex(); tinytex::install_tinytex()` to reinstall it.

Comment: I think `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` can fix it, but it will be great if you can help me figure out what went wrong so I can do better in tinytex. First, try `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` in the R console. If that doesn't fix the problem, try `tinytex::tlmgr(c('install', '--reinstall', 'l3backend'))`. If it still doesn't work, try `tinytex::tlmgr(c('install', '--reinstall', 'l3kernel'))`. Let me know if any of these steps fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I can try those. I tried all those three commands, and the knitr output messages and errors remained exactly the same. Is there anything else you'd like me to test before trying uninstall_tinytex() and install_tinytex()?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Please try to set a CTAN repo ( e.g., `tinytex::tlmgr_repo('https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/')`) and retry these steps.

Comment: You are running LaTeX with a L3 programming layer from August (see near the top of the .log file where it says "L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>"), but somehow the backend files are already from the recent release of the L3 prog layer, e.g. l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-10-10. Not sure why the mismatch is not detected (normally that should happen) but anyway that mismatch is the cause as many commands with "e" expansion have been added (and then used in the kernel file) in that release from  2023-10-10.

Comment: try to recreate the formats (`fmtutil-sys --all`).

Comment: The R function `tinytex:::refresh_all()` will run `fmtutils-sys --all`. @carusis Could you check if it fixes the problem?

Comment: I ran these commands, and tried knitting after commands 2 to 5, it still didn't work.

tinytex::tlmgr_repo('https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/')
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
tinytex::tlmgr(c('install', '--reinstall', 'l3backend'))
tinytex::tlmgr(c('install', '--reinstall', 'l3kernel'))
tinytex:::refresh_all()

Comment: (as in, I tried knitting after tlmgr_update(), and again after tlmgr(c('install', '--reinstall', 'l3backend')), etc.)

Comment: `tinytex:::refresh_all()` alone should fix the problem. If not, I guess the only way out for you is to reinstall TinyTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` solved it.

Comment: See comments above -- I did try this, and it worked. I also tried a few other things before that at request of @yihui-xie